# jQuery select span class not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-textext

Im trying to select the span by using the (.class) selector but for one or another reason this is not working.

```
<div class="text-wrap">
<div class="text-list">
  <div class="text-suggestion">
     <span class="text-label">Lorem</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('.text-label').click(function(e){
            alert('lol');
        });
});
```

I can only select .text-wrapper the others are not working.. is this a jQuery program fault? I also have to say that im using the jQuery textext plugin.

UPDATE:

I forgot the quotes in my first post but this is not the problem. The code is also in a script tag otherwise it would not be possible to select the text-wrap div.

I still have the problem that everthing that is in the text suggestion div can't be triggered.

I am using the textext plugin from [Textext](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/ajax-with-autocomplete.html)

ANOTHER UPDATE afther the comment:

```
jQuery("#customfield_10000").keyup(function(e){
                            teller = teller + 1;
                            if(teller % 2 == 0){
                            if(e.keyCode == 13)
                            {
                                jQuery("#customfield_10001").focus();
                            }    

            crmAccount = jQuery(this).val();
            lijstAccounts.length = 0;

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "http://"+serverIp+"/getAllAccountNamesJsonP?jsonp_callback=?",
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        jsonp: "jsonp_callback",
                        data: {
                            featureClass: "P",
                            style: "full",
                            maxRows: 12,
                            name_startsWith: jQuery(this).val(),
                                                            crm_acc: crmAccount,
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                lijstAccounts.length = 0;
                                 jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
                                                            lijstAccounts.push(item);
                                                            jQuery('#customfield_10000').trigger(
                                                                'setSuggestions',
                                                            { result : textext.itemManager().filter(lijstAccounts, query) }
                                                            );              
                                    return {
                                        label: item.label,
                                        value: item.value    
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }); 
                            }
        });

jQuery('#customfield_10000').textext({
                plugins : 'autocomplete'
                }).bind('getSuggestions', function(e, data)
                    {

                        textext = jQuery(e.target).textext()[0],
                        query = (data ? data.query : '') || '';

                    });
```

Comment: others are not working? what do u mean by this, didnt get you?

Comment: Ive i do jQuery('text-wrap').click(function ..)  the event is fired but on text-label the event NEVER got fired and it exists i see it in the firebug

Comment: tried your above code...when i clicked to lorem it shows alert as lol... didnt find any error... have u included jquery.js ??

Comment: what is Texttext plugin doing with this piece of code here as i don't see any textarea or textboxes?

Comment: +1 to sujal.. that's what even i feel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't see any problem with your code.. check the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rutwik/buCpr/), it's just the copy paste of your code. I think you don't have any jquery script included in the page. Try to include one and that should solve your issue

in the jsfiddle i included Jquery 1.7.2.

Comment: Yeah , im closing this question i think its more a jira issue.. Im using this into a jira plugin. Everything runs fine it's only not possible to get the selected result from the autocomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Your query needs to be within `<script>` tags. Also add quotes as needed.

```
<div class="text-wrap">
<div class="text-list">
  <div class="text-suggestion">
     <span class="text-label">Lorem</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text-label').click(function(e)){
        alert('lol');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-wrap">
<div class="text-list">
  <div class="text-suggestion">
     <span class="text-label">Lorem</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('.text-label').click(function(e){
            alert('lol');
        });
});
</script>
```

I think you have forgot to include jquery script try this.. copy whole script and save it in .html file then try it once

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-wrap">
<div class="text-list">
  <div class="text-suggestion">
     <span class="text-label">Lorem</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('.text-label').click(function(e){
            alert('lol');
        });
});
</script>
```

Works fine with me. Have you missed the jquery library or the  tags